# Cumsum with nan values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pass a cumulative sum of unique values to a separate column. However, I want to disregard nan values so it essentially skips these rows and continues the count with the next viable row.

```
d = {'Item': [np.nan, "Blue", "Blue", np.nan, "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Red"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['count'] = df.Item.ne(df.Item.shift()).cumsum()
```

intended out:

```
   Item  count
0   NaN    NaN
1  Blue      1
2  Blue      1
3   NaN    NaN 
4   Red      2
5  Blue      3
6  Blue      3
7   Red      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['count'] =(df.Item.ne(df.Item.shift()) & df.Item.notna()).cumsum().mask(df.Item.isna())
```

OR

as suggested by [`@SeanBean`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15070697/seabean):

```
df['count'] =df.Item.ne(df.Item.shift()).mask(df.Item.isna()).cumsum()
```

Output of `df`:

```
    Item    count
0   NaN     NaN
1   Blue    1.0
2   Blue    1.0
3   NaN     NaN
4   Red     2.0
5   Blue    3.0
6   Blue    3.0
7   Red     4.0
```

Comment: How about just use `df.Item.ne(df.Item.shift()).mask(df.Item.isna()).cumsum()` at the right side ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

*NOTE:* (you just need to add the where condition):

```
df['count'] = df.Item.ne(df.Item.shift()).where(~df.Item.isna()).cumsum()
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   Item  count
0   NaN    NaN
1  Blue    1.0
2  Blue    1.0
3   NaN    NaN
4   Red    2.0
5  Blue    3.0
6  Blue    3.0
7   Red    4.0
```